# What is the name of `¬` character on the keyboard and what is it primary purpose since I never see it in normal text or programming code?

Tags: keyboard, special-characters

What is the name of this `¬` character on the keyboard and what is used for?

The duplicate answers don't quite explain its main usage, and why a character such as this takes up space on keyboards with limited keys when it's hardly used in common prose or program code.

Other than the suspicion that it may be useful in drawing some boxes, what is its common use case and how common is that use case for most computer users?

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67163557/117259) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/290163/108394).

Comment: The duplicate might be going further into how to get rid of it, but does answer this as well.

Comment: What kind of keyboard is this? I never saw a keyboard with that symbol on it.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt It's on my UK keyboard

Comment: I see. Does the Wikipedia article on US and UK keyboard layouts at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards help?

Comment: On a Mac it's on opt/L & is used to make a new line in code without it being *read* as a new line - so visually for human legibility only. In unicode it's called the NOT SIGN U+00AC

Comment: The main usage of any key is to use that key. The use of an "A" key is to type an "A" in a document and the same goes for `¬`. Given the meaning of the key (read the duplicate) it is obviously more useful for mathemeticians and scientists than "normal" users, but obviously someone somewhen thought that the British needed it more for some reason. Why they chose it is going to be lost to time and probably opinion based now and how many people use it is a question for surveys and polls.